# Outcodes in Cohen-Sutherland Clipping Algorithm

Tags: clipping

What advantages do the outcodes offer in [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland_algorithm) ? Do they help in simplifying the algorithm ? Do they decrease the number of calculations ?

Comment: Your question could probably be improved by including some more information about the actual algorithm instead of just linking to it. Posts should generally be self-contained so as not to be susceptible to link rot (even though that's unlikely for Wikipedia) and so that people can understand the full question without having to read an external link first.

Answer (score 3):

The outcodes just represent four boolean flags as a bitfield. Codewise it is easier to move a bitfield around than four booleans. Functionality-wise it becomes very easy to check if *any* bits are set (just check if zero), and combining outcodes is as simple as a bitwise OR.

On a side-note: Since bit-operations are fast, it is not a performance issue that the individual bits need to be extracted (e.g. outcode & BOTTOM).